# Azure blob storage

Tags: azure, cloud, blob, storage

I am just wondering whether there is a possibility to access privately the blob storage within an azure service (let's say from a worker role) instead of accessing files through the public address (which basically send your files over the internet, leaving the cluster). The same question i have for storage queues or for Storage Tables ... are they accessible using a private endpoint (LAN HTTP address by IP or sort of)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Today it is not possible to access Azure Storage privately. The traffic must route through public Internet.

There's a feedback item on the same on Azure's feedback site - https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217298-storage/suggestions/6954656-storage-accounts-on-vnet-or-disable-key-options. From the status, it seems Azure Storage team is currently reviewing this though no time line has been specified for that. Feel free to upvote this request.